# Bad audit? (Question without error message)

Tags: discussion, review-audits, specific-audit, first-questions

I did not fail this one, but I think it's a bit unsuitable for an audit.

[GCC disagrees with Clang and MSVC when concept that's always true is used to implement a concept](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69823200/6699433)

> The following code fails to compile with Clang 13 and MSVC v19.29 VS16.11 but successfully compiles with GCC 11.2.
>
> <Code block>
>
> <Link to Godbolt>
>
> Is GCC wrong here? I expected `refable<void>` to evaluate to false since it forms an invalid type(`void&`) in the immediate context.

My immediate reaction to this was to downvote and/or close vote because the error message is not included in the question. While it can be discussed if it's strictly necessary in this case, I would argue that it would 1) improve the question a lot since error messages are searchable, and 2) I don't think it's fair that someone should fail an audit when downvoting for this reason.

Comment: The question was unclear to you because it lacked the error message? Or... you just have some "template" in mind of what is an acceptable question that you are slavishly following?

Comment: " improve the question a lot since error messages are searchable" - perhaps, but that does not imply the question in its current state is bad. It would go from good and useful and answerable by people who know the compilers (that domain knowledge, so important) to Good with a capital G.

Comment: @CodyGray I would argue that there is some middle ground between robo reviewing and spending half an hour to make sure you understand every little detail of a question to the level that you can answer it instead of reviewing it. It was unclear to me primarily because I did not have enough knowledge of this particular subject.

Comment: @Gimby I'm not saying it implies that it's bad. I'm saying that it's not very suitable as an audit. Especially since it has been made clear that the audits are there to make sure the reviewer is "paying attention" and "cheating" by opening the question in a separate tab to see if it's an audit is considered paying enough attention to not be considered a robo reviewer.

Comment: Absolutely; I am not one to argue that anyone should spend more than a few minutes reviewing each question. I certainly don't, or wouldn't. If you don't understand it well enough because you lack sufficient knowledge, then you should "Skip" it.

Comment: @CodyGray Thing is, it's not always easy to know if you lack the sufficient knowledge or not. To be completely sure about that, you almost need to be able to answer it.

Comment: @klutt and if you're not completely sure, what's the harm in 'skip'? You took a risk, admitting you don't know the domain. With risks come consequences sometimes. Like here. It happens

Comment: @Patrice There's no harm in skipping. Where did I write such a thing? I actually skip most of them. But if people only reviewed those questions where they are able to answer it, the queue would fill much faster than it can be emptied. The most risk free thing one can do is completely stop reviewing, and that would not be good.

Answer (score 6):

It is a `[language-lawyer]` question. In essence, it is a question about what it should be according to the standard, rather than about a specific compiler's behavior.

Sure, results for different compilers make the question better. Posting the error might make it even better (though it is a "static assertion failure" error for [MSVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B), and doesn't convey any more information. The [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) error is better, but it still does not help to make the question *searchable*).

But it is fine with just giving the author's expectation (*I expected `refable<void>` to evaluate to false since it forms an invalid type (`void&`) in the immediate context.*), and reason to hesitate in it (*The following code [...] successfully compiles with GCC 11.2.*).

Comment: This question is not about if the original question is fine or not. I'm asking if the question is suitable as an audit or not.

Comment: It is the same answer: if the original question is fine for Stack Overflow, then the audit is also valid. Why would we need to make a distinction?

Comment: @CodyGray Because some questions are *clearly* good questions. Others are *clearly* bad questions. Those two categories are good as audits. Those questions that are note *clearly* good or bad are not good for audits. At least not as long as the purpose of the audits is to just make sure that you're not just robo reviewing to get a badge.

Comment: @klutt *"Those questions that are note **clearly** good or bad are not good for audits."* - Surely if something is not _clear_ to you, then you should be using the _Skip_ button?